# NETSDK1013: The TargetFramework value 'v4.7.2' was not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, dotnet-test

I am running unit tests on a .NET project against a specific version of .NET framework and I am using following command:

```
dotnet test --framework v4.7.2
```

But when running this, I am getting following error:

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(92,5): error NETSDK1013: The TargetFramework value 'v4.7.2' was not recognized. It may be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly.

Is there anything that I need to change?

Comment: Have you tried `net472`? I think, a TFM (target framework moniker) must be used here.

Comment: You need to use the correct Target Framework Moniker (TFM), in this case `net472`. All supported TFMs are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)